# Constant kCGColors deprecated on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, deprecated

I'm having some trouble getting CGColorGetConstantColor() to work on the iPhone. Apple's documentation [claims](http://developer.apple.com/iPhone/library/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGColor/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGColorGetConstantColor) you can pass any of the "Constant Colors" without linking to what the Constant Colors actually are, so I assumed you can simply use those [documented for OS X](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/graphicsimaging/Reference/CGColor/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Constant_Colors):

```
CGColorRef blackColor = CGColorGetConstantColor(kCGColorBlack);
```

This does not seem to be the case however, as Xcode throws me this error: "'kCGColorBlack' is unavailable (declared at /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator3.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Headers/CGColor.h:123)"

Anyone know what the new constants are (and where they're documented)?

Comment: Why is the method there, but the constants deprecated? Makes no sense.

Answer (score 11):

Have a look at UIColor:

```
CGColorRef blackColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
```